# How do I make my own adapter methods able to consume a trait object?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait that has "adapter methods" that consume the method:

```
struct Bar<T>(T);

trait Foo {
    fn make_bar(self) -> Bar<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Bar(self)
    }
}

impl Foo for u8 {}
impl Foo for bool {}
```

This is modeled after `Iterator`. When I use a `Box<Iterator>`, I can still call `Iterator` adapter methods like `map` or `filter`:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let b: Box<Iterator<Item = u8>> = Box::new(a.into_iter());
    let c = b.map(|x| x * 2);
    for z in c {
        println!("{}", z)
    }
}
```

However, the methods I've defined don't work in the same way:

```
fn main() {
    let a: Box<Foo> = Box::new(42);
    a.make_bar();
}
```

This fails with the errors

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:18:7
   |
18 |     a.make_bar();
   |       ^^^^^^^^ `Foo` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `Foo`
```

It's absolutely correct that `Foo` does not have a size - it's a trait. However, `Box<Foo>` *should* have a size, as I understand it. What is `Iterator` doing differently from my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Iterator` is object safe, the trait object `Iterator` implements `Iterator`.

Because `impl<I: Iterator + ?Sized> Iterator for Box<I>`, the boxed trait object `Box<Iterator>` implements `Iterator`.

Thus in your case the solution is to implement `Foo` for `Box<Foo>`. This could be generic like `Iterator`’s (`impl<T: ?Sized + Foo> Foo for Box<T> { }`) or it could be specific (`impl Foo for Box<Foo> { }`).

Comment: Oh, `impl MyTrait for Box<MyTrait>` — that's a lot simpler than I expected. I was looking at the [source of `Iterator`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/0aeb9f6f08c353c71d962d5cc7a231e73040ca3c/src/libcore/iter.rs) which didn't mention `Box` at all; I should have just looked at the implementation list in the docs instead :-)